# Controlling transparency color when scaling PNGs as JPEGs

Tags: html5-canvas, fine-uploader

When I upload a PNG image with transparency, the transparent part becomes black after JPEG conversion.

The desired result is to have the transparent portion white on my converted JPEG image.

This is a portion of my fineuploader config :

```
extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'],
files: ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg'],
multiple: true,
scaling: {
    sendOriginal: false,
    defaultType: 'image/jpeg',
    sizes: [
        {name: "", maxSize: 300},
        {name: "", maxSize: 2048}
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When scaling image files, Fine Uploader draws the image onto an `HTMLCanvasElement`, scales it, and then turns it into a `Blob`, which can then be uploaded just like any other file. If the desired output container is a PNG, then the alpha channel data *should* remain intact. However, if you choose JPEG as the target container, that is a different story.

As you may know, JPEGs don't have a concept of transparency. The HTML5 specification dictates exactly how this situation should be handled:

In [section 4.11.4.2 - Serializing bitmaps to a file](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#serializing-bitmaps-to-a-file), the spec states:

> For image types that do not support an alpha channel, the serialized image must be the bitmap image composited onto a solid black background...

So, this is the expected behavior, and there is little that can be done to work around this. I suppose it may be possible, with enough research and tinkering, to change this color, but this is not something I plan to incorporate into the library. If you have more specific requirements for scaled images, your best course of action is to scale them server-side with something like ImageMagick. Your other option, in this case, is to output the images as PNGs by setting [the `scaling.defaultType` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#scaling.defaultType) to 'image/png'.

Comment: You would just have to add a `default_background` argument to your function and then do `ctx.fillStyle = default_background; ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)` before drawing the uploaded image

Answer (score 1):

After a long journey of investigation and fails, I finally got it.

Here is the solution I found and it works for me.

in `line 10442 : function renderImageToCanvas(img, canvas, options, doSquash)` I added this code

```
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
 ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
 ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 0);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF"
 ctx.fill();
```

just before `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);`

for more understanding this code please make some researches on converting png to canvas and the transparency.

Good luck